# How to empty browser cache after clicking logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use Go for my server side and angularjs for client.
When I logout of my application, the cache is still present.
How can I empty the complete cache at a button click?

Comment: even though, I use cache control, few pages are still getting cached...

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0" />
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />